# Replace Javascript click event with timed event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found some javascript code that layers photos on top of each other when you click on them.

Rather than having to click I'd like the function to automatically run every 5 seconds.  How can I change this event to a timed one:

```
$('a#nextImage, #image img').click(function(event){
```

Full code below. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#description').css({ 'display': 'block' });
    $('#image img').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('hover'); }
    );

    $('a#nextImage, #image img').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#description p:first-child').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' });
        if($('#image img.current').next().length) {
            $('#image img.current').removeClass('current').next().fadeIn('normal').addClass('current').css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
        }
        else{
            $('#image img').removeClass('current').css({ 'display': 'none' });
            $('#image img:first-child').fadeIn('normal').addClass('current').css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
        }

        if($('#image img.current').width() >= ($('#page').width() - 100)) {
            xPos = 170;
        }
        else {
            do {
                xPos = 120 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * ($('#page').width() - 100)));
            } while(xPos + $('#image img.current').width() > $('#page').width());
        }
        if($('#image img.current').height() >= 300) {
            yPos = 0;
        }
        else{
            do {
                yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
            } while(yPos + $('#image img.current').height() > 300);
        }
        $('#image img.current').css({ 'left' :xPos, 'top' :yPos });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try setInterval function. It runs something every N milliseconds. It looks like:

```
setInterval(function() {
  alert('5 seconds over!');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#description').css({ 'display': 'block' });
    $('#image img').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('hover'); }
    );

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#description p:first-child').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' });
        if($('#image img.current').next().length) {
            $('#image img.current').removeClass('current').next().fadeIn('normal').addClass('current').css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
        }
        else{
            $('#image img').removeClass('current').css({ 'display': 'none' });
            $('#image img:first-child').fadeIn('normal').addClass('current').css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
        }

        if($('#image img.current').width() >= ($('#page').width() - 100)) {
            xPos = 170;
        }
        else {
            do {
                xPos = 120 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * ($('#page').width() - 100)));
            } while(xPos + $('#image img.current').width() > $('#page').width());
        }
        if($('#image img.current').height() >= 300) {
            yPos = 0;
        }
        else{
            do {
                yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
            } while(yPos + $('#image img.current').height() > 300);
        }
        $('#image img.current').css({ 'left' :xPos, 'top' :yPos });
    }, 5000);
});
```